# Why would CROSS APPLY not be equivalent to INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

This runs in 2 minutes:

```
SELECT    
    G.GKey,
    Amount = SUM(fct.AmountEUR)
FROM      
    WH.dbo.vw_Fact fct 
    INNER JOIN #g G ON
       fct.DateKey >= G.Livedate AND
       fct.GKey = G.GKey 
GROUP BY G.GKey;
```

This runs in 8 mins:

```
SELECT    
    G.GKey,
    C.Amount 
FROM      
    #g G
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT
           Amount = SUM(fct.AmountEUR)
        FROM 
           WH.dbo.vw_Fact fct 
        WHERE
           fct.DateKey >= G.Livedate AND
           fct.GKey = G.GKey 
    ) C;
```

These are both quite simple scripts and they look logically the same to me.

Table #G has 50 rows with a clustered index `ON #G(Livedate,GKey)`
Table `WH.dbo.vw_Fact` has a billion rows.

I actually felt initially that applying the bigger table to the small table was going to be more efficient.

My experience using `CROSS APPLY` is limited - is there an obvious reason (without exploring execution plans) for the slow time?

Is there a 'third way' that is likely to be quicker?

Comment: I suspect the reason has nothing to do with using APPLY but is actually caused by the triangular join in here. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/61539/

Comment: @SeanLange good reference. Can I amend the CROSS APPLY version so that it is set based?

Comment: @whytheq is vw_fact a view and if so how complex is the underlying query in the View? Are there any indexes on the vw_fact?

Comment: Here are a couple of excellent references explaining APPLY. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/APPLY/69953/ http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/APPLY/69954/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the logical difference between the two joins:

`CROSS APPLY`: yields the Cartesian cross product of an aggregation on a given value of `LiveDate` and `GKey`, this gets re-executed for every row.

`INNER JOIN`: yields a 1-to-1 match on vw_Fact for every value of `LiveDate` and `GKey`, then sum accross common values of `GKey`, this creates the joined set first, then applies the aggregate.

As some of the other answers mentioned, cross apply is convenient when you join to a table valued function that is parameterized by some row level data from another table.

Is there a third way, that is faster? I would generally suggest not using open ended operators in joins (such as `>=`). Maybe try to pre-aggregate the large table on `GKey` and some date bucket. Also, set up a non-clustered key on `LiveDate` including `AmountEUR`

Answer (score 0):

I think you trying to get `Rolling sum`. use [**Over() clause**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms189461.aspx) Try this.

```
SELECT G.GKey,
       Amount = Sum(fct.AmountEUR)
                  OVER(
                    partition BY G.GKey
                    ORDER BY id rows UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
FROM   WH.dbo.vw_Fact fct
       INNER JOIN #g G
               ON fct.GKey = G.GKey
```

Comment: no - I'm not trying to get a rolling sum. I just want the sum.

Comment: @whytheq - fine,did you try executing this query

Comment: Whoever ever **down-voted** can you please comment why this is not useful

Comment: I didn't downvote but I suspect the reason is that the answer is irrelevant (i.e. the question is not about a running total). To be honest, I'm surprised to find that this answer's got upvoted, and more than once too.

Comment: @AndriyM - Even my answer does the same thing as what OP is trying to achieve.

Comment: Haters gonna hate. My advice? Forget about the imaginary internet points and just keep pluggin'. :)

Comment: Now that I've taken a closer look, I can definitely say that your query will return *very different* results to OP's. Both queries in the question will return one row per `GKey`, yours will potentially return multiple rows per `GKey`.

Comment: @BenThul: I'm happy to say that in this particular case it's not about hating. :)

Answer (score 0):

`APPLY` works on a row-by-row basis and is useful for more complex joins such as joining on the first X rows of a table based upon a value in the first table or for joining a function with parameters.

See [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/607246/Making-OUTER-and-CROSS-APPLY-work-for-you) for examples.

The obvious reason for the cross apply being slower is that it works on a row by row basis!

So for each row of #g you are running the aggregate query in the cross apply.